# javascript float, double, decimal

Tags: javascript

is there a way to convert a java script number 1, to a decimal or float or double value like this 1.00?

I want to have a drop down box with values from 1 to 10, it is a payment method to select how much money you want to pay and of course i want to make my user enter his own value like 4.30 or just 4 and when he does, the 4 has to be converted to 4.00 not string but number, i used `parseFloat().toFixed(2)` and it converts to string, i DON'T need that..

Comment: Why do you need the leading zeros?

Comment: @Juhana because it revolves around money

Comment: So? `4` is the exact equivalent of `4.00`. You should care about the zeroes only when you're printing the value to the user.

Comment: parseFloat(Math.round(a * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) found this seems usefull, well i need to display the decimal points.. don't ask why :/

Comment: That's exactly the same what you have in the question (and returns a string). In any case "4.00" is always a string; numbers don't keep track of leading zeroes.

Comment: @Juhana So, what do you propose i should do? display numbers without zeroes?

Comment: No. As I already said, *when you print the numbers* add the leading zeroes. When you're doing calculations with them treat them as numbers (and ignore the zeroes because they don't have any meaning.) But why do you not want it to be a string? It has to be a string if you're printing it.

Comment: @Juhana Well i didn't know that it was this easy to convert between numbers and strings in JS :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with switch statements, where you can play with the length of the value.